# Is there a listing of natural numbers with their properties?

Tags: natural-numbers

I am looking for a category of natural numbers (about <1000 is enough) with its properties.

Here's some examples :

2 - It is the first prime number.

1729 - It is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two cubes in two different ways.

Here's some bad examples that I don't focus on :

36 - It is the number that its half is equal to multiplying each digits (3 and 6 in this case).

69 - It is the number which has a sexual meaning.

36 is the bad example because it depends on the base 10.

Is there any site about this?

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia article [List of numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numbers) links to articles about individual numbers. They have covered all natural numbers up to 1000, and some beyond that range.

I like the subheading of the article:

> This is an *incomplete list* which may never be able to satisfy particular standards for completeness. You can help by expanding it ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "category" is quite what you mean, maybe "catalogue"?  Anyway as a printed reference there's [David Wells' Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7L7xcjBPemEC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) 
and online, there are wiki entries for small integers, e.g. [37](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/37_%28number%29)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.numbergossip.com/69 (for example). Please see thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921/interesting-numbers-in-maths

Answer (score 0):

A site that has some curiosities about natural numbers are http://primes.utm.edu/curios/ but as any site that lists curiosities it will be incomplete but perhaps it satisfies your needs.